# Using Windows 10 system user input prompt via python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create native Windows 10 system prompt for user inputs using python. The type I am talking about is, the native system prompt one gets in, say a User Access Control prompt for password. I tried searching a lot but am not able to find anything.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post something that you have tried and then ask a specific question if you still need help

Comment: @JackHanson I am not able to find anything that can lead me to something that I can try; hence the question.

Comment: maybe the input function in Python is what you need? What do you want the program to do?